# << operator override compiles with g++ not windows

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, operator-overloading, name-lookup

I am trying to port an application to win-dows (ironic, I know). The following bare-bone example illustrates the problem. I get the following error when compiling with VS12 and VS14:

> ```
> C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand
> of type 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,std::chrono::system_clock::duration>'
> (or there is no acceptable conversion)
> ```

No errors on Ubuntu with g++. What am I missing?

**logger.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <ostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> &time_point);

namespace Logging
{
    inline std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> timestamp()
    {
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        return time_point;
    }

    class Event
    {
    public:
        Event() : time_point(timestamp())
        {
        }
        typedef std::unique_ptr< Event > Ptr;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Ptr &p)
        {
            out << p->time_point << "\t";  // << LINE CAUSING ERROR
            return out;
        }

    private:
        const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time_point;
    };
}
```

**logger.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <memory>
#include <ctime>
#include "logger.h"


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> &time_point)
{
    std::time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time_point);
    struct tm t;
    localtime_s(&t, &time);  //localtime(&time) on linux
    char buf[30];
    int ret = ::strftime(buf, 30, "%Y/%m/%d %T", &t);
    out << buf;
    return out;
}
```

**commands and flags**

linux:

`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall logger.cpp app.cpp -o app`

windows:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\chron_test.pch"
```

Comment: Excuse me, what are the flags used for compilation with gcc and msvc?

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg see edit

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: @M.M see edit (line 27 marked with << LINE CAUSING ERROR)

Comment: @M.M Uggghhh.. thank you for trying VS 2017. I am stuck with 2013 Pro (13) at work. Tried at home with 2015 Community (14).. same problem.

Comment: @M.M Unfortunately the original Linux version uses `struct timespec` flawlessly. This was my first attempt. Maybe I will have to try a different route.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the code at first... ignore my previous comment

Comment: Are you sure that the exact sample you posted gives the error?

Comment: @M.M It was actually helpful. Maybe I should just use the `std::put_time` instead

Comment: @M.M Yes. The Linux version of the above sample is slightly different because it uses localtime instead of localtime_s. But the framework is identical.

Comment: Actually I reproduce the problem with MSVC 2015 online tester , it is a name lookup issue. Does it fix the error if you put `using ::operator<<;` on the line before the one giving the error?

Comment: @M.M. Yes! Thank you! Looks like I need to do a little more reading on `using` You should make an answer so I can give you some credit.

Comment: Yeah I have just been investigating the root cause of the issue, will write an answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short answer:* It is a compiler bug in MSVC 2015 and older; to work around it, write `using ::operator<<;` just before the line giving the error.

---

This issue concerns name lookup of inline friend definitions. 
Here is a simplified example of the problem:

```
namespace R { struct S {}; }
void f(R::S) {}

namespace N
{
    struct E
    {
        R::S var;
        friend void f(E e) { f(e.var); }   // OK, should find f(R::S)
    };
}
```

Generally, unqualified name lookup will do two things:

- Look for the name in the current scope. If not found, look in the parent scope, etc. up to and including the global namespace. **Stop when we find the name**. That is, if the name is in the current scope and also in a parent scope, then the name in the parent scope would NOT be found.
- ADL, i.e. also search the namespaces of any arguments to the function call.

Note that in this code `f(R::S)` is not declared in namespace `R`, so it is never found by ADL. It can only be found by the first part of unqualfiied lookup.

So there is a potential problem that any name `f` occurring inside `namespace N` may hide the global `f`. You can see this in action if you remove the `friend` line and put `void f(E e) { f(e.var); }` as a function in `N` (not in `E`). Then the name lookup finds `N::f`, and stops searching, never finding `::f`.

Now, name lookup of a `friend` function *first defined* inside a class is a bit unusual. Quoting from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend):

> A name first declared in a friend declaration within class or class template X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but is not visible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that considers X) unless a matching declaration at the namespace scope is provided.

That means that in the call `f(e.var)`, the function `N::f` is actually not visible for lookup. So the search should keep going up scopes until we find `::f`, and succeed.

MSVC 2015 does seem to know about this friend lookup rule, as it correctly rejects `struct A { friend void a() { a(); } };` , however it then fails to continue looking up the outer scopes for another declaration of the name.

The `using ::operator<<;` declaration means that the search of `N` will find `::operator<<`; seeing as MSVC 2015 accepts this, apparently it is still searching `N` but just not recursing upwards if that search fails.

---

*Commentary:* This problem with function names being shadowed is always a problem when you have `operator<<` which is not found by ADL.  Even in a correct compiler, you may find your code annoyingly stops working when you have some unrelated `operator<<` interfering. For example if you define an `operator<<` in `namespace Logging` then , even in g++ and MSVC 2017, the code will stop working.

The same `using ::operator<<` workaround works in this case, but it's annoying to have to keep doing that.  You really have to do `using ::operator<<` inside any namespace `N` that declares its own `operator<<` of any sort, which is still annoying but a bit less so.  It may be preferable to use a function with a somewhat unique name, instead of `operator<<`, for this purpose.

Note that it is not possible for `operator<<(std::ostream, std::chrono...)` to be found by ADL, because all of the arguments are in `std` but `::operator<<` is not in `std`.  It is undefined behaviour to add your own free functions to `namespace std`, so you can't work around it that way either.

Comment: I'm sure there will be a canonical question discussing the shadowing issue although I'm not finding it with a search

Comment: Excellent answer. It is always nice learning new things! Thank you again for the help (and superb formatting).